# Moving character on a specific stage Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game with ActionScript 3.0. There's is one thing I can't figure out: 
I have a big circle on the background. On this circle I want to let a character randomly move. But this character can only move on this circle, so it can't go to the background. Where do I need to start with this, how can i specify a specific stage like this?

P.S. I can't upload a picture yet, I've not enough "reputation points", otherwise I would have uploaded some pictures to get my question more clearly.

Comment: If you mean you want to make a character walk around a circle rather than along a straight line, you need to know at least the basics of trigonometry and mathematics associated with circles i.e. Pythagoras Theorem for measuring the distance from the centre of the circle and adjusting rotation and movement along an arc.

Comment: I think Ernst is aiming to make the character walk randomly within a circular area, and not let him exceed the bounds. Not sure if this is fit for SO, it looks like you simply want someone to write this for you. Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 0):

A general idea around which you can evolve is using `hitTestPoint()` method on your stage using current player's coordinates as the point being tested, and if this method returns false, this means the player has left the stage, and you need to put him back. Using previous location is the failsafe method, but you might also invent some other more smart way to do this.

[The manual on `hitTestPoint()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29)